# Is there a way of using Python to change an image in multiple documents?

Tags: python, excel, image, ms-word

My company is undergoing a re-brand and as such the logo has changed. We have hundreds, if not thousands of word and excel docs that have the old logo. Can I use python to find and replace the image?
I found a code (below) that would do this for text (replacing Adber with Abder), can it be modified to change images?
import os, re

```
directory = os.listdir('/')
os.chdir('/Users/')

for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'r')
    read_file = open_file.read()
    regex = re.compile('Adber')
    read_file = regex.sub('Abder', read_file)
    write_file = open(file,'w')
    write_file.write(read_file)
```

Comment: sounds like a very risky task, you might end up corrupting the docs. It will depend what type of file are the docs (e.g. doc or docx( , how the image was pasted, et c.

Comment: My plan was to use back up documents to trial any methods before rolling out across the board. Most files are saved as docx

Comment: There is a library, docx, for word docx manipulation in python but I'm not sure how good is with picture, have a look here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/